# shell script call asyncronus function and hold exit

Tags: bash, shell, asynchronous

I'm writing an shell script like these:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
y=`expr $2 / $1`

while [ $x -ne "$1" ]; do
    a=`expr $y \* $x`

    ./validade_database.sh 1 $a $3 $4 $5 `expr $y \* $x` &

    x=`expr $x + 1`
done

read inputline
```

The problem is that it's calling my "validade_database.sh" just one time. I've tried this:

```
echo "./validade_database.sh 1 $a $3 $4 $5 `expr $y \* $x` &"
```

And it shows that it's called $1 times.

My second problem is when I stop this script, it keeps running the "validade_database.sh" in background, how do I stop them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't noted what `$1` is.

Assuming `$1` is `1` then the script would run exactly one time.